# Apply a rule to calculate sum of specific

Tags: r

Hi I have a data set like this.

```
Num   C     Pr      Value   Volume
111   aa    Alen      111    222
111   aa    Paul      100    200
222   vv    Iva       444    555
222   vv    John      333    444
```

I would like to filter the data according to Num and to add a new row where take the sum of column Value and Volume but to keep the information of column Num and C, but in column Pr to put Total. It should look like this way.

```
Num   C     Pr      Value   Volume
222   vv   Total     777     999
```

Could you suggest me how to do it? I would like only for Num 222.

When I try to use `res` command I end up with this result.

```
#  Num  C    Pr   Value Volume 
1: 111 aa  Alen   111    222
2: 111 aa  Paul   100    200
3: 111 aa  Total   NA     NA
4: 222 vv   Iva   444    555
5: 222 vv  John   333    444
6: 222 vv Total    NA     NA
```

What cause this?

The structure of my data is the following one.

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ Num   : Factor w/ 2 levels "111","222": 1 1 2 2
  $ C     : Factor w/ 2 levels "aa","vv": 1 1 2 2
  $ Pr    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Alen","Iva","John",..: 1 4 2 3
  $ Value : Factor w/ 4 levels "100","111","333",..: 2 1 4 3
  $ Volume: Factor w/ 4 levels "200","222","444",..: 2 1 4 3
```

Comment: The desired output is not clear. Do you want it for each `Num` or only for `Num` 222?

Comment: Can you show the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: You have `factor` columns for Value and Volume.  You need to convert that to `numeric` columns to take the sum.  `df1[4:5] <- lapply(df1[4:5], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Num', 'C' columns and specifying the columns to do the `sum` in `.SDcols`, we loop those columns using `lapply`, get the `sum`, and create the 'Pr' column.  We can `rbind` the original dataset with the new summarised output ('DT1') and `order` the result based on 'Num'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT1 <- setDT(df1)[,lapply(.SD, sum) , by = .(Num,C), 
              .SDcols=Value:Volume][,Pr:='Total'][]
rbind(df1, DT1)[order(Num)]
#   Num  C    Pr Value Volume
#1: 111 aa  Alen   111    222
#2: 111 aa  Paul   100    200
#3: 111 aa Total   211    422
#4: 222 vv   Iva   444    555
#5: 222 vv  John   333    444
#6: 222 vv Total   777    999
```

---

This can be done using `base R` methods as well.  We get the `sum` of 'Value', 'Volume' columns grouped by 'Num', 'C', using the formula method of `aggregate`, `transform` the output by creating the 'Pr' column, `rbind` with original dataset and `order` the output ('res') based on 'Num'.

```
res <- rbind(df1,transform(aggregate(.~Num+C, df1[-3], FUN=sum), Pr='Total'))
res[order(res$Num),]
#  Num  C    Pr Value Volume
#1 111 aa  Alen   111    222
#2 111 aa  Paul   100    200
#5 111 aa Total   211    422
#3 222 vv   Iva   444    555
#4 222 vv  John   333    444
#6 222 vv Total   777    999
```

EDIT: Noticed that the OP mentioned `filter`.  If this is for a single 'Num', we `subset` the data, and then do the `aggregate`, `transform` steps.

```
transform(aggregate(.~Num+C, subset(df1, Num==222)[-3], FUN=sum), Pr='Total')
#  Num  C Value Volume    Pr
#1 222 vv   777    999 Total
```

Or we may not need `aggregate`.  After `subset`ting the data, we convert the 'Num' to 'factor', loop through the output dataset ('df2') get the `sum` if it the column is `numeric` class or else we get the first element and wrap with `data.frame`.

```
df2 <- transform(subset(df1, Num==222), Num=factor(Num))
data.frame(c(lapply(df2[-3], function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
                   sum(x) else x[1]), Pr='Total'))
#  Num  C Value Volume    Pr
#1 222 vv   777    999 Total
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Num = c(111L, 111L, 222L, 222L), C = c("aa", "aa", 
"vv", "vv"), Pr = c("Alen", "Paul", "Iva", "John"), Value = c(111L, 
100L, 444L, 333L), Volume = c(222L, 200L, 555L, 444L)), .Names = c("Num", 
"C", "Pr", "Value", "Volume"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Your comment is not clear.  I also showed the data I used. Can you try on the data from my post?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjj Why do you use `res`? Use the **EDIT** to the answer.

Comment: @akrun When i try with `res` command. I end up with this output. for total. `#5 111 aa Total   3    3`  and                                                                       `#6 222 vv Total   3    3`  Why it not take the sum of it?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjj  Initially, I thought that you want `res` output, but later I edited to have only a single row output.  Based on the data I showed, I am getting the `sum`.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjj  BTW, I am using the devel version of data.table.  Instructions to install the devel version are [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).  In case, there is a difference in version..

Comment: @akrun. Thank you for all this great information. I really appreciate the time and effort you've given me!  P.S. Once again sorry if I ask you silly questions.

Answer (score 3):

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(Num == 222) %>% 
    summarise(Value = sum(Value), 
              Volume = sum(Volume), 
              Pr = 'Total', 
              Num = Num[1], 
              C = C[1]) 
#   Value Volume    Pr Num  C
# 1   777    999 Total 222 vv
```

where we first `filter` to keep only `Num == 222`, and then use `summarise` to obtain the sums and the values for `Num` and `C`. This assumes that:

- You do not want to get the result for each unique `Num` (I select one here, you could select multiple). If you need this, use `group_by`.
- There is only ever one `C` for every unique `Num`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `dplyr` package:

```
df %>%
  filter(Num == 222) %>%
  group_by(Num, C) %>%
  summarise(
    Pr = "Total"
    , Value = sum(Value)
    , Volume = sum(Volume)
            ) %>%
  rbind(df, .)

#   Num  C    Pr Value Volume
# 1 111 aa  Alen   111    222
# 2 111 aa  Paul   100    200
# 3 222 vv   Iva   444    555
# 4 222 vv  John   333    444
# 5 222 vv Total   777    999
```

If you want the total for each `Num` value you just comment a `filter` line

Comment: And if you want the total for each `Num` value you just comment a filter line